# Typing Test, how to make input save when spacebar is pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

My friend and I were building a typing test. We are using the input() function in python to get input from the user. The problem is that we have to press enter to make the input save and we want that button to be spacebar instead. Is there any way to do this or another module we could use to solve this problem?

```
for i in range(num_words):
  print(final_sentence)
  print("")
  typed_word = input("Type>")
  words_to_list(typed_word)
  os.system('clear')
```

Comment: You will probably want to use a module that reads keystrokes directly, not `input` (which only reads complete lines from standard input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use other modules like [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) or [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) because `input()` detects whole strings while those modules detect key presses. Detect key presses, print them, and stop when Key.space (in pynput case) is pressed.
Something like this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
from pynput.keyboard import Key

words=''
def on_press(key):
        if key==Key.space:
            listener.stop()
            print (words)

def on_release(key):
        global words
        typed = str(key).replace("'", "")
        words = words + typed

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

This code detects key press using pynput.keyboard's handy listener, and adds it to words until space is pressed. When space is pressed the script stops the listener and prints the typed sentence.